# How to use Prolog's foreach/2 loop

Tags: prolog, eclipse-clp

I am trying to get the `foreach/2` loop to work in Prolog (using tkeclipse). I understand it needs an element in the first argument and a list to search for that element within as a second argument.

My problem is that I haven't been able to make it work despite trying to rewrite my code and looking for solutions online.

In the following code, I try to write a predicate `visite/2` that takes a list of museums and returns a list of cities where they are located.

Your help would be really appreciated as it would allow me to be better prepared for my upcoming exam.

```
musee(paris,louvre).
musee(rome,vatican).
musee(madrid,prado).
musee(berlin,kulturforum).
musee(londres,british_museum).

visite([X],L) :-
  findall(V,musee(V,_),List),
  (
    foreach(X,List) do findall(C,musee(C,X),L)
  ).
```

Answer (score 1):

ECLiPSe's do-loops are a shorthand for writing iterative recursions in a concise way.  A simple application to your example would be

```
visite(Ms, Cs) :-
    ( foreach(M,Ms), foreach(C,Cs) do
        musee(C, M)
    ).
```

which is (modulo nondeterminism) equivalent to the explicit recursive form

```
visite([], []).
visite([M|Ms], [C|Cs]) :-
    musee(C, M),
    visite(Ms, Cs).
```

An algorithmically completely different way to solve your problem is using backtracking and findall, as in

```
visite(Ms, Cs) :-
    findall(C, (member(M, Ms), musee(C, M)), Cs).
```

Both are useful Prolog programming patterns.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't Prolog (at least, not as I know it).

And if it were, the notion of an iterative loop is antithetic to Prolog.

Your problem statement:

> I [am trying to write] a predicate `visite/2` that takes a list of museums and returns a list of cities where they are located

could be better done in a way more idiomatic to Prolog. Something like this:

```
musee( paris   , louvre         ).
musee( rome    , vatican        ).
musee( madrid  , prado          ).
musee( berlin  , kulturforum    ).
musee( londres , british_museum ).

%
% Accepts a list of museums and returns the list of cities (villes) in which they are found.
% Or... vice versa.
% 
% We invoke a helper predicate that will prevent problems if/when the predicate
% is used in a generative manner.
visite( Ms,Vs ) :- visite( Ms, [], Vs ).

visite( []     , _ , []     ) .
visite( [M|Ms] , T , [V|Vs] ) :-
  musee(V,M) ,
  \+ member( M:V, T ),
  !,
  visite( Ms, [M:V|T], Vs )
  .
```